# how to display messages without reloading the page?

Tags: php, ajax

Hello guys I want to display a message sent by user that can be seen in other user without reloading the page. What is the best approach to solved this problem? I tried reloading the div but nothing happened.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#load_mesgs").load(" #load_mesgs > *");
  });
</script>
```

Comment: How do you know a message is received? There is an event? Please post more detailed information

Comment: It's like a chatting but in realtime